# Flask: show contents before time-consuming function completes

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app which when routed to `/compute` evaluates a *time-consuming* function `f`.

```py
...the usual flask stuff here...

@app.route('/compute')
def compute():
    result = f() # this can take several seconds
    return render_template('page.html', computed_result = result)
```

After the visitor goes to `/compute`, how can I display the user a page with 'pls wait' text until the `result` is obtained?

I've searched but didn't get a direct solution.

Comment: You need to change the architecture to event driven. Put `f()` in a celery task and make it async,

Comment: @PouyaEsmaeili thanks. I've unfortunately no experience with celery. Could you please expand your answer a bit? My background isn't in the web development area. A code snippet would be great.

Comment: Yes, sure. Let me explain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you need to make the architecture event-driven by using celery task manager. `f()` is defined as a task and called async.
Define `f()` as a task with celery in a specific file (e.x. `task.py`) like this:

```
from celery import Celery

# Creating a celery instance with redis as message broker.
app = Celery('my_task', broker='redis://localhost')


@app.task
def f(arguments):
    """
     This is a celery task. Just a normal function with task decorator.
     Note that we use the decorator from a celery instance.
    """
    pass  # do f here
    # save the result in database or cache and map it to task id
```

After the abouve definition, you need to import `f()` from `task.py` and call it by passing arguments like this:

```
...the usual flask stuff here...
from task import f  # import f function from task.py

@app.route('/compute')
def compute():
    result = f.delay(arguments)  # call f async like this
    return render_template('page.html', computed_result_task_id = result.task_id)  # You can't return the result unless wait for the result, so just return the task id and get the result later via another API. 
# save task result in a database or cache and map to task_id for further retrieval
```

It was a brief introduction, use the [documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org) for details of implementations.

And also, you need to execute the task like this:

```
celery -A task worker -l ERROR --detach
```

(There are more options to run and manage a task in documentation.)

Comment: Thank you very much. The structure is clear to me. The only part where I'm doubtful is this: "..get the result later via another API. You need to define backend for your celery app to keep and serve the results." I'm unsure about how/where 'catch' the computed result and use it as an input for the template.

Comment: Your welcome. Yes that part was ambiguous, I updated the answer. I meant you need to save task result in a database or cache engine for further retrieval. And also it is necessary to keep a mapping between the results and task id. After that, task result could be fetched by implementing another API accepting task id as an argument.